# How do I configure Evolution to cache an online contacts/address book for faster and offline usage?

Tags: email, exchange, contacts, evolution

I use Evolution for my work email configured to use Exchange Web Services. There is an address/contact list that will show up sometimes when I am typing in the address recipient of my email. This is very helpful when it works, but often it does not show up at all.

Is there a way to cache this list or do something else to make Evolution show the address list more consistently?

My evolution version:

```
evolution 3.46.4 (3.46.4-1.fc37)
```